# ELASTICSEARCH - Unlimited size inner hits elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to be able to return all the values ​​that the query finds.
I have tried to specify in the size field of inner hits more than 100, but it returns an error indicating that a parameter greater than 100 is not possible
How can I change so that it returns all the results that it finds regardless of the size, whether it is less than or greater than 100?

error:
"reason" : "Inner result window is too large, the inner hit definition's [null]'s from + size must be less than or equal to: [100] but was [101]. This limit can be set by changing the [**index.max_inner_result_window**] index level setting."
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the value by changing the index settings, like this:

```
PUT your-index/_settings
{
   "index.max_inner_result_window": 1000
}
```

Be aware, though, that you're going to take a performance penalty depending on the size of your index.

Comment: Thank you again Val, your help is always very usefull

Comment: @val if we take care of performance then can you suggest a better way to approach this?

Comment: @Vishnu feel free to create a new question with your requirements.

Comment: @Val Question created could you please have a look into this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64172796/elastic-search-performance-related-queries-for-large-volume-of-data